# Sunflower oil on dried cherries

Tags: fruit

I'm making some sort of low alcohol kriek type beer, and just picked up a few pounds of dried cherries from Cosco.  When I got home I noticed the last ingredient on the cherries is sunflower oil.

I'm pretty sure I know the answer is "no."  But is it safe to use these cherries?  They have no fat, so there really can't be much oil on them.

Comment: The fat content is just below the limit per serving required to put on the nutritional info panel. I don't have an answer, but I'd be concerned about the oil and my head retention on the finished beer. It is starting to be cherry season, why not use fresh.

Comment: I ended up going to a farmers market, a stand had the most sour cherries I've ever tasted, worked out perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naw if they have sunflower oil listed on them, then I'd eat them separately and find something else to put in the beer. Not sure if you guys have the Publix grocery store up in Boston, but they carry dried cherries that you can buy in bulk and only have one listed ingredient ("dried cherries").